# how to store the API response value to useReducer initial state

Tags: reactjs

```js
import {useEffect, createContext} from 'react';
import DisplayDate from "./components/DisplayDate";
import React from "react";

export const Context= createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "IN":
      return{
        ...state,
        date:(new Date(state.date.date).getDate()+1)
      }
    case "out":
      return{
        ...state,
        date:(new Date(state.date.date).getDate()-1)
      }
    default:
     return state;
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer,{
    date: new Date(),
    user: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('../../data/user.json').then((response)=>response.json()).then((data)=>{
      state.user=data
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('../../data/date.json')
     .then((response)=>response.json())
     .then((data)=>{
      state.date=data
     })
     .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
 })
 console.log(state)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="buttons">
        <Context.Provider value={{dispatch:dispatch,state:state}}>
            <DisplayDate />
        </Context.Provider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm fetching date and user information which is stored in JSON file using fetch API, I want to save that API response to useReducer initial state and want to increase date value by 1 or decrease the value by 1 based on action. but when I'm doing console.log of state return by useReducer, first its return current Date then date fetch from API. How to display the data fetch from date API on first render.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be part of the **initial** state, then you need to already have the data at the time the component renders for the first time. That will require splitting the component up. You'll have one component that loads the data, waits for it, and then renders the second component which does `useReducer` with an initial state.

```
const OuterComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('../../data/user.json').then((response)=>response.json()).then((data)=>{
      setValue(data)
    })
  })

  if (!value) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return <InnerComponent value={value}/>
  }
}

const InnerComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer,{
    date: new Date(),
    user: value
  });

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's still giving the same result.